# You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders, r = ts(a[0])

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm

**I'm using react typescript and simply want to create a select component for a time zone picker. I tried using npm library react-timezone-select. But it is giving the below errors in the console:**

index.js:1 ./node_modules/react-timezone-select/dist/esm/index.js 9693:38

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9693:38)

File was processed with these loaders:

./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js

You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

```
r = ts(a[0]);
let o = "",
s = n.isDST() ? r[0].daylight?.abbr : r[0].standard?.abbr,
l = n.isDST() ? r[0].daylight?.name : r[0].standard?.name;
const u = 60 * t.current.offset,
```

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong. Can't use npm libraries in react typescript?

I tried installing react-timezone-select using the below commands

```
npm i react-timezone-select
npm i @types/react-timezone-select
```

Also, I changed the `tsconfig.json` file to include

```
"lib": ["DOM", "ES6", "DOM.Iterable", "ScriptHost", "ES2016.Array.Include", "esnext"],

"include": ["src", "backend", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"]
```

but none of it worked and the same error is persistent.

I expected typescript to make life easier but instead, it creates more problems with every other npm library.

Answer (score 0):

It seems updating the react-scripts to 5.0.1 fixes your problem. Refer to this thread https://github.com/ndom91/react-timezone-select/issues/57